# Освобождение памяти в Stack'e

Tags: c#, память, clr

Всем известно,что с Stack это некий участок памяти,который аллоцируется на каждый поток в виде размера **1МБ** , в нем хранятся ссылки(ObjRef) на **ReferenceType**,пользовательские структуры,примитивные данные,ну и локальные переменные метода.

А теперь вопрос: что делает **CLR**, когда Stack полностью заполниться, и соответственно удалять по сути нечего.То бишь Stack переполнен?

Может ли CLR расширить его границы с 1МБ до 2МБ?(или это не возможно,в связи с чем,мы просто получим **Exception**, который оповестит нас о переполнении стека).

Другой вопрос: в контексте **unsafe** кода,unamanged участку памяти выделяется так же 1МБ или аллоцировать можно кастомный размер?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для начала стоит отметить что стек в момент выполнения кода - это не какой-то абстрактный safe-механизм. .NET использует JIT-компиляцию, так что в реальности выполняется код, привязанный к конкретной платформе, с использованием механизма стека этой платформы. В случае x86 - сегмент стека + пара регистров SS/ESP и операциями push/pop. Никакого отдельного стека для unsafe не создается.

Что происходит при заполнении стека и можно ли его увеличить по достижению лимита? Нет, в общем случае - нельзя.

Дело в том, что стек, по крайней мере в x86/64 - это структура данных, заполняемая с конца. Т.е. каждое помещение чего-то в стек сдвигает его указатель ближе к началу. Это идет из древних (еще до-.net) времен, когда памяти было мало, и стандартное разделение памяти выглядело так:

```
[код][данные-куча --> ....... пустое место....... <-- данные-стек]
```

Физическая память делилась между кучей и стеком, и у программиста всегда был выбор - выделить побольше памяти под что-то в куче, или положить побольше объектов в стеке. К тому же такая раскладка эффективно избавляла от необходимости контролировать размер отдельно кучи, и отдельно - стека. Т.к. если в ней куча и стек встретились - то памяти не осталось совсем.

С тех пор многое поменялось (хотя раскладка выше все еще актуальна на некоторых микроконтроллерах). В x86 Для стека теперь обычно выделен отдельный сегмент. Но он, по традиции, заполняется с конца. Т.е. каждая операция push уменьшает значение SP на размер положенного в стек.

По достижению ESP значения 0 - процессор выбрасывает ошибку. Механизма "довыделения памяти" в стеке в x86 нет - просто потому, что нельзя "довыделить" память в начало сегмента - а выделить память в конце и переложить все данные в стеке процессор не осмеливается - для него это слишком сложная операция. Это могла бы сделать операционная система, но по крайней мере Windows на x86 так не поступает.

На выходе по достижению 0 указателем стека вы получаете `StackOverflowException` в вашем коде .NET. Это индикатор достижения лимита "железного" стека, а не какого-то хитрого стека CLR.

---

Стоит отметить, что к `StackOverflowException` на x86 может привести также бесконечная рекурсия, причем даже в случае если вы не объявляете локальные переменные. Дело в том, что механизм вызовов методов на x86 (`call`) сохраняет в стеке адрес возврата из вызываемого метода. А оператор возврата (`ret`) достает адрес из стека. Поэтому слишком глубокая цепочка вызовов забивает стек.

Собственно, именно поэтому окно просмотра вызовов и называется Call Stack - информация цепочке возврата хранится только в стеке. Причем на x86 - в том же физическом стеке что и параметры фунций и локальные переменные.

Comment: Отлично,благодарю :)

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить, что будет если мы переполним данные в куче? У нас же будет расти объем используемой оперативной памяти? Но при переполнении стека, оперативная память не забивается. Разъясните пожалуйста

Comment: @user2455111 Если куча переполняется - clr просто выделяет еще памяти. Куча не обязана быть физически непрерывной. Т.е. куча - это сложная вещь, обычно состоящая из нескольких кусков/сегментов памяти, которой управляет GC/рантайм. На нее можно посмотреть с помощью windbg/sos/!eeheap -gc. У кучи нет какой-то готовой железной реализации, которая ее как-то ограничивала бы.

Comment: @user2455111 А стек - это дико простая вещь, с железной реализацией на уровне процессора. Это заранее выделенный сегмент фиксированного размера. По сторонам от него лежат другие данные. Для работы с ним у процессора есть всего два регистра - SS (адрес сегмента) и ESP (положение посленего впушенного элемента). При переполнении - занять память рядом - нельзя, она обычно уже занята чем-то. Выделить второй кусок памяти под стек еще где-то (как делает CLR для кучи) - нельзя - у процессора всего два регистра для стека, он не умеет куски. Вот он и падает.

Comment: @PashaPash последний комментарийстоит в ответ добавить, такие детали уже очень не многие знают, хотя по идее это основы