# Переполнение системного стека (не структуры данных)

Tags: стек

Как стек знает, что он переполнен?
Когда программа проверяет, не переполнен ли стек?
Что происходит при переполнении стека?

Comment: Уточните, в каком контексте Вас интересуют упомянутые вопросы.

Comment: Почитайте [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31397305/7286264) хорошо и кратко для Linux описано.

Comment: тут была затронута эта тема, может поможет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606790/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-stacke/606808

Answer (score 7):

> Как стек знает, что он переполнен?

Об этом знает операционная система. Она, в свою очередь, узнаёт об этом при попытке программы прочитать из или записать в страницу-«ловушку» сразу под стеком. «Ловушка» здесь — это невыделенная страница, к слову зарезервированная и потому никому не выделяемая даже случайно.

> Когда программа проверяет, не переполнен ли стек?

Например, для Windows: программа может обработать [SEH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

> Что происходит при переполнении стека?

Например, для Windows: операционная система генерирует исключение  `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW` (определено в `winnt.h`). Если программа не обработает полученное исключение, а попытается использовать память за выделенным диапазоном - возникнет исключение "нарушение доступа". А вот в этом случае операционная система прибъет не только поток, который попытался воспользоваться большем чем ему доступно памятью стека потока, но и завершит аварийно весь процесс.

ADD: Про *nix системы надо почитать, пока освежил знания по Рихтеру)

Comment: На *nix-системах при переполнении стека ОС кидает сигнал SIGSEGV. Его можно отловить и обработать.

Answer (score 5):

Железный стек процессора (в x86) - это два регистра: ESP и SS.

SS - это адрес сегмента стека (адрес самого стека в памяти)
ESP - это указатель на текущее положение последнего элемента в стеке.

В самом начале он выставляется на *конец* стека. И при помещении новых элементов - он уменьшается.

т.е. стек в памяти выглядит так

```
другие данные][ пустое место в стеке            | занятое место в стеке ][другие данные
              ^--- расстояние = значению ESP ---^
```

по мере заполнения картина меняется на

```
другие данные][ |              занятое место в стеке                    ][другие данные
              ^^
```

и в конце концов ESP достигает значения 0 и уходит в минус.

процессор оказывается в ситуации

- стек заполнен
- разбить на две части процессор его не может - т.к. это невозможно организовать на двух регистрах. и процессор слишком туп для этого. не его это дело.
- расширить стек он не может - он подперт другими данными с двух сторон. Ну и опять же - не его это дело.
- переместить стек в другое место он не может - Не его это дело. Вдруг разработчик передал адрес чего-то в стеке в стронний код и не ожидает, что стек переедет?

Может только упасть. Процессор кидает ошибку Stack-Segment Fault, его ловит операционка.

Операционка оказывается в точно такой же ситуации, что и процессор - не ее дело чинить переполненный стек + она не может принять решение за программиста. Так что она разбирается с программой в меру своих возмоностей - прокидывает ошибку в виде исключения SEH, Exception в .NET или просто убивает процесс.

Теоретически корректно побороть Stack Overflow может рантайм с автоматическим управлением памяти (вроде .NET) - тем, что он может спрятать разработчика детали реализации, и запретить захватывать указатели на объекты в стеке. Это уберет последнее ограничение в списке, и позволит переместить стек в другую область памяти, выделив под него побольше места.

На практике ни один фрейморк так не делает из соображений простоты и производительности и красоты. Stack Overflow - это почти всегда ошибка разработчика. Лучше (и проще!) упасть, и заставить его исправить ошибку, чем скрывать ее путем скрытого перемещения больших объемов памяти.

---

Стоит отметить, что описание выше значительно упрощено - примерно до уровня x86 protected mode времен 486/Pentium. На самом деле *современные* операционные системы выделяют физическую память страницами + используют флаги защиты на страницах для обнаружения переполнения стека. Подробно (с картинками) об этом можно почитать у Рихтера, в книге "Создание эффективных Win32-приложений с учетом специфики 64-разрядной версии Windows", главе "Стек потока".

---

Рост в сторону уменьшения сделан ради упрощения проверки - на 0 проверять проще, да и размер стека хранить не нужно. На других архитектурах (не x86) стек вполне может расти в другую сторону - но проблему это не решает - т.к. все ограничения из списка выше остаются актуальными.

Comment: Немного некорректное описание выделение памяти на стеке. Рекомендую http://www.e-reading.by/bookreader.php/135055/Rihter_-_Windows_dlya_professionalov:_sozdanie_effektivnyh_Win32-prilozheniii_s_uchetom_specifik....pdf  (ввести страницу 418 в поиск)

Comment: @Majestio там windows-specific реализация. я упростил до уровня стандартной x86 protected mode реализации (с бросанием 12-го исключения) для простоты понимания - потому что вся теория защищенного режима, с дескрипторами и защитой доступа к памяти не влезет в ответ - про это можно книгу написать, с картинками :)

Comment: @Majestio допишу подробоно в ответ чуть позже

Comment: Согласен. Завтра буду искать для FreeBSD и Линукса. Мельком на англоязычном SO чего-то писалось.

Comment: `ESP достигает значения 0 и уходит в минус` — неправда. Между стеком и началом адресного пространства есть много чего такого, куда нельзя писать и читать: невыделенная память и страницы кода с правом только на чтение и выполнение.

Comment: @Arhad да, Majestio выше писал об этом, и в ответе об этом тоже есть примечание со ссылкой в Рихтера

Comment: Я к тому, что ESP никогда не достигнет нуля — не успеет. Исключение будет выброшено на первом же байте за пределами стека.

Comment: @Arhad да, если операционка использует страницы-ловушки. Современные операционки - используют. Но не обязаны. Про это же сказано в ответе :)

Comment: Теперь всё понятно, спасибо. Действительно, начал комментировать, не дочитав ответ до конца.

Comment: @Arhad подход со страницами-ловушками расписан в ответе у Majestio. В моем ответе расписан более древний вариант обнаружения (и про это сказано в ответе). Я просто не хочу переписывать чужой ответ в свой ради полноты  картины - пусть лучше он получит заслуженные плюсы.

Comment: *"прокидывает ошибку в виде исключения SEH, Exception в .NET или просто убивает процесс"* - вообще-то, процесс умирает сам, в процессе обработки исключения SEH :)

Answer (score 2):

> Как стек знает что он переполнен?

никак. Он не умеет думать.

> Когда програма проверяет не переполнен ли стек?

а программа этого не делает. Это задача операционной системы. Она выделяет приложению немного памяти под стек (обычно 1 мегабайт, и это можно настраивать). Как только приложение начинает писать в много данных в стек и выходит за пределы выделенного места - операционная система прибивает приложение.

Но в целом, приложение может знать, сколько места под стек ему выделено и сколько стека по факту уже занято. И если занятно больше какого-то объёма (допустим 95%), записать в лог/написать письмо.

> Что происходит при переполнении стека?

Обычно операционная система прибивает приложение и дальше может сделать дамп памяти или запустить отладчик. Но это уже проблема не приложения

Comment: а когда операционная система проверяет не переполнен ли стек? И может ли операционная система не прибыть приложение, когда переполнен стек?

Comment: она проверяет по факту доступа к памяти.

Если приложение не прибивать, то ему нужно выделить больше стека. Может просто сразу выделить побольше?

Comment: то есть после переполнение стека можно увеличить стек?

Comment: @Тарас я недавно отвечал на вопрос про увеличение стека - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606808/. Там применительно к .NET, но стек там по сути тот же самый.

Comment: Память под стек выделяется постранично, но не более максимально определенного объема. Далее - сгенериться исключение, чтобы программа смогла как-то по-другому поступить с памятью. Впрочем я все расписал в своем ответе.

Comment: Операционная система ничего не прибивает при переполнении стека. Это делает .net. А в других языках вполне можно обработать.

Comment: ОМГ! Прочтите устройство Windows, книжек валом) .NET - это просто библиотека, это не компонента операционной системы.

Comment: @Majestio  Qwertiy имел ввиду, что решение "умирать или нет" принимает приложение (и только оно, т.к. оно может SEH), а не операционка (как написано в в ответе).

Comment: а если приложение не умеет seh?

Comment: Он неправильно написал! Умоляю - почитайте Рихтера. Если EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW не обработано, сразу вылетит второе исключение "ошибка доступа" и **операционная система** снимет приложение. А вот если приложение обработает EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW и **не будет пытаться** захватить памяти больше чем надо - приложение будет работать.

Comment: @KoVadim, SEH - это "поделка" Windows. В стандартах языка нет контроля стека. Да и быть не может - операционных систем и аппаратных архитектур много, и все разные.

Comment: я знаю, что такое seh. И я сильно сомневаюсь, что автор вопроса тоже знает. Но пойдем дальше - он не указал ось и язык программирования. Поэтому, исходя из опыта, для автора вопроса ответ просто - скорее всего приложение умрет. А вот для тех специалистов, которые научились минусовать, но не прокачали телепатию, нужно отдельно объяснять. 

Мой комментарий "а если приложение не умеет seh" относится и к тем случаям, когда на целевой платформе seh не возможен.

Comment: Понятное дело, "если на целевой платформе SEH невозможен", нужно искать "а что возможно".

Comment: нужно лечить причину, а не последствия. Если стек переполняется, значит кому то это нужно:) например, закравшемуся багу.

Answer (score -5):

> Как стек знает, что он переполнен?

По мере заполнения указатель стека уменьшается. А он, к слову сказать, беззнаковый. Когда он достигнет нуля, очередная попытка что-то в него поместить вызовет ошибку переполнения (ну на самом дел заёма). Вот тебе и сигнал.

> Когда программа проверяет, не переполнен ли стек?

Программа тупо проверяет текущее значение указателя стека. Если она очень тупая, то на нулевое значение, если не очень тупая - то сравнивает его с неким пороговым, ниже которого могут возникнуть проблемы. Но это как. А когда? да когда программист решил, что надо проверять...

> Что происходит при переполнении стека?

В лучшем случае - плевок в неиспользуемую область памяти. В плохом - ошибка защиты памяти. В худшем - неопределяемое разрушение памяти, чреватое подменой.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51358/discussion-on-answer-by-akina------).